# Passing interpolation value through ngModel

Tags: html, angular

```
<input [(ngModel)]="newVariablesAttribute.Steps" 
class="form-control" 
type="text" readonly 
name="{{newVariablesAttribute.Steps}}">
{{stepname}}
```

I want to pass stepname (which I am able to show in the frontend using interpolation) using ngModel.

But It is not working.

[image]

Comment: did you try `[(ngModel)]="stepname"` (https://angular.io/guide/template-syntax#ngModel), and any error in browser console.?

Comment: Post your code properly.

Comment: It will not work because this ngModel has many attributes and i am passing it directly to the database,

Comment: <input [(ngModel)]="newVariablesAttribute.Steps" class="form-control" type="text" readonly name="{{newVariablesAttribute.Steps}}">{{stepname}}

Answer (score 0):

Since stepname is getting rendered in the UI, you can pass it to the ngModel directly like this right -

```
<input [(ngModel)]="stepname" 
        class="form-control" 
        type="text" readonly 
        name="{{newVariablesAttribute.Steps}}">
{{stepname}}
```

(I guess newVariablesAttribute.Steps are some array of objects. )

Comment: even it is array of objects, it still shows [object, object] in the textbox

Answer (score 0):

Didn't find any issue with your code. Steps might be undefined

**Component**

```
export class SomeComponent {
newVariablesAttribute = {
    Steps: 'step'
  };

  stepname = 'abc';
}
```

**html:**

```
<input [(ngModel)]="newVariablesAttribute.Steps" class="form-control" type="text" readonly name="{{newVariablesAttribute.Steps}}">{{stepname}}
```

**O/P**

[image]